# Fixing in-range nested loops

Tags: python, variables, loops, range, nested

I'm having a problem getting this program to work and it's about 2:00am here so I really just want to get it over with. Anyways, I'm required to create a program in which the total sum and average of donations over several weeks (input by the user) is calculated and displayed. This program uses nested loops to collect data and calculate the average.

The way it works is:

- The program asks for the number of weeks
- An outer loop iterates once every week
- An inner loop iterates 5 times per week
- Each iteration of the inner loop asks the user for an amount of donation
- After all iterations, the sum of the donations and the average of the donations over each week is displayed

There are three main problems that I have in creating this program. The first is that my nesting of loops is not working the way I want it to.

```
weeks = input("How many weeks available for collection? ")

for donation_week in range(0, weeks):
    for donation_day in range(0, donation_week*5):
        amount = input("How much money was donated today? ")
        break

week_total = amount * 5
collection_total = week_total * weeks
average = collection_total / weeks

print "In", weeks, "weeks, a sum of", collection_total, "was collected and an average"\
                   " of", average, "was donated each week"
```

For example if the user inputs 3 weeks, I expect the program to get the amount 5 times per week, so 15 times. But it doesn't, and instead only asks for an amount twice.

Second problem is when the user inputs 1 week or 0 weeks, an error occurs which states 
"NameError: name 'amount' is not defined"

The final problem is something I actually haven't touched on yet in the coding, which is how I will calculate the week's total (week_total) if the user inputs different amounts each day. I only state amount as one variable when really, there are 5 amount variables for 5 days of the week.

Again, I'm very new to python and my instruction guide really don't touch upon specifics like these. I've been trying rearranging and changing this program for two hours or so now, and I'm still pretty stuck. Hoping someone here can share their knowledge. Much thanks.

Comment: You don't want to have the user input this one-by-one; if they make a mistake they will be cursing at whoever made the program. =) You want to read in a text file or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your questions one at a time:

> For example if the user inputs 3 weeks, I expect the program to get the amount 5 times per week, so 15 times. But it doesn't, and instead only asks for an amount twice.

As mentioned, that's because of your break, just get rid of that and it will do it more than once.

> Second problem is when the user inputs 1 week or 0 weeks, an error occurs which states "NameError: name 'amount' is not defined"

Well, lets trace it through with a week of 1:

```
for donation_week in range(0,1): #range(0,1) == [0]
    for donation_day in range(0, 0*5): #during the first (and only) loop, donation_day is 0, so do no loops
```

So, when it gets past the loop, the line that sets `amount` never executes, so amount isn't defined. Try defining it as 0 at the top of your program to avoid that problem.

Also, there's no reason for the second for statement to be `in range(0, donation_week*5)`, actually that's completely wrong if you want it to ask for 5 every week. If you want that, it should just be `in range(5)` (Also the 0 is assumed if the start is not set explicitly) so it will do that loop 5 times for each week. The way you have it, the first week it will ask 0 times, the second it will ask 5, the third 10, etc.

> The final problem is something I actually haven't touched on yet in the coding, which is how I will calculate the week's total (week_total) if the user inputs different amounts each day. I only state amount as one variable when really, there are 5 amount variables for 5 days of the week.

If you make it so that amount is defined at the top of the program as 0, you can just add the input to amount each time you get it. It won't keep track of how much was donated on each day, but it works perfectly if you just want totals and averages.

So, if you initiate amount at the top of your program and also change the `amount = input` line to `amount += input` to keep track of the running total (Also likely get rid of week_total and collection_total, I don't see it having a use anymore) and fix the logic within your for loop like I mentioned, you should be golden.

Comment: Stay gold Ponyboy. Stay gold. I completely forgot about the += operation and that it easily tracks amounts by itself. I extremely appreciate your answer as I was ready to give up because its just those little specifics that get past me as I'm usually so focused on keeping it detailed and structured, when really there are simple solutions to most of my problems. Anyways thanks again, I love this site because it actually helps me a great deal through feedback but I need to learn not to rely on it as often as I already do for such simple errors. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the `break` statement causes the inner loop to terminate early.

Secondly, you have to compute the running total inside the loop (or at least keep the values somewhere). Currently, you keep overwriting `amount` with every iteration.

Lastly, the `week_total` and `collection_total` logic looks suspect. Just keep the running sum of daily amounts, and in the end divide it by the number of weeks to get the weekly average.